# Simple html dom parser get tr from table

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping, html-table, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrap `http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/`but here i just want get `Proxy by ip:port` column only 
i checked the website there was 3 table

Anyone can help me out?

```
<?php
    require "scrapper/simple_html_dom.php";

    $html=file_get_html("http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/");
    $html=new simple_html_dom($html);

    $rows = array();
    $table = $html->find('table',3);

    var_dump($table);
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem. The code in question has no errors, but it does not show any efforts for solving the actual problem (getting required columns). Also, please provide sample input in question itself, not as a an external link.

Comment: actually, i want to scrap the proxies from `spys.one` , how to do that with simple html dom parser ?

Comment: You're basically asking us to write the whole code for you. This is not how SO works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below script. It should fetch you only the required items and nothing else:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = "http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/";

$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find("table[width='65%'] tr[onmouseover]") as $file) {
    $data     = $file->find('td', 0)->plaintext;
    echo $data . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Output it produces like:

```
 176.94.2.84
 178.150.141.93
 124.16.84.208
 196.53.99.7
 31.146.161.238
```

Comment: nice sir, but how to get the port too ?

Answer (score -1):

I really don 't know, what your simple html dom library does. Anyway. Nowadays PHP has all aboard what you need for parsing specific dom elements. Just use PHPs own [DOMXPath class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) for querying dom elements.

Here 's a short example for getting the first column of a table.

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('https://your.url.goes.here');

$xpath = new \DomXPath($dom);

// query the first column with class "value" of the table with class "attributes"
$elements = $xpath->query('(/table[@class="attributes"]//td[@class="value"])[1]');

// iterate through all found td elements
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo $element->nodeValue;
}
```

This is a possible example. It does not solve exactly your issue with `http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/`. But it shows you how you could easily get the first column of a specific table. The only thing you have to do now is finding the right query in the dom of the given site for the table you want to query. Because the dom of the given site is a pretty complex table layout from ages ago and the table you want to parse does not have a unique id or something else, you have to find out.

Comment: sir, here the table don't have attribute class , and there are 3 tables so how ?

Comment: I 've checked the site before. But StackOverflow is not a site for giving you full solutions for your issues. It 's all about examples, how you could solve your issue for yourself. Positive side effect: you learned something. All you need is shown in my example. Just find out for yourself, which query is the right one for querying the contents of the specific table of the given website. I 'm not here to do your job, mate. ;)

Comment: Really? A downvote because you have to think for yourself? Thank you!